# Save PNG files instead of JPEG

Tags: xcode, uiimage, shader, swift5

I use `UIActivityViewController` to share my `UIImage` (save to Photos). I found that quality of saved image is lower then I can see it in my app (it is created by shaders), especially on small details of it. It looks like image is compressed.

The coded is simple:

```
let items = [img]
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
```

Is it possible to choose PNG lossless format instead of JPEG when it is shared?

Answer (score 1):

Well, solution is quiet simple:

```
let items = [img.pngData()]
```

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. When I share saved image it sends it as PNG, but before it was JPG.

Comment: That's fascinating that the activity view controller can take a `Data` and figure out that it is a PNG. It obviously must be resorting to some magic bytes logic.